# How can you use Create() and Update() in the same Django HTML page?

Tags: python, django

I am trying to create a page where I can create a new entry/note to a list and also update an existing list on one HTML page. The problem is create() does not require a primary key. However, update() requires existing primary key. How can do I do this in django? Do I create a new function in views.py? Example:

```
def new_note(request, note_id=None):
    if note_id == None:
        notes(request) #function that just uses create()
    else:
        note_sad(request, note_id) #sad=save and delete using update() and delete()

views.py sample function for entering notes:
def notes(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        notes = Note.objects.all().order_by('note_id')
        form = NoteForm()
        return render(request=request,
                      template_name='notes.html',
                      context={
                          'notes': notes,
                          'form': form
                      })

    # when user submits form
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = NoteForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            note = form.cleaned_data['note']
            Note.objects.create(note=note)
        # "redirect" to the todo homepage
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('new_note'))

views.py function for creating a new entry/note:

def note_sad(request, note_id):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        note = Note.objects.get(pk=note_id)
        form = NoteForm(initial={'note_text': note.note_text})
        return render(request=request,
                      template_name='notes.html',
                      context={
                          'form': form,
                          'note_id': note_id
                      })

    if request.method == 'POST':
        if 'save' in request.POST:
            form = NoteForm(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                note = form.cleaned_data['note']
            Note.objects.filter(pk=note_id).update(note_text=note)
        elif 'delete' in request.POST:
            Note.objects.filter(pk=note_id).delete()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('new_note'))
```

Comment: What have you tried? what error are you getting? are you block at a specific part?

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to pass the ID to `note_sad`  for updating the object. One way is when you display the items on your HTML and add Id for each submit button as follows:

```
{% for note in notes %}
    <input type='submit' value='{{note.pk}}' name='pk'>
{% end for %}
```

Alternatively, you may add the Id to the form as follows:

```
<form method = "post" action="{% url 'note_sad' note.pk %}">

{% csrf_token %}
       
</form>
```

Comment: can you please explain the syntax of {% url 'note sad' note.pk %}? the quote note sad is the function being called in views.py obviously but what does note,pk do?

Comment: hi @Rocky `url` is basically calling the your `note_sad` path defined in your `url.py` that refers to `note_sad` in your `view.py` and then pass the note `id` as parameter. In HTML you can refer to object id as `pk` through `note.pk`. I am assuming that in your `url.py` you have already defined a path for `note_sad` method and named it `note_sad`.

Comment: can I email you? I still don't understand django html syntax. {% url(what does it mean) 'note_sad'(what should be put in quotes? views.py function?)  note.pk(what is this parameter/variable do?) %}. Can you please explain in detail? Are you on WhatsApp?